# how to pass value to struct dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I am trying to form an URL dynamically.

where I am using Struct to construct it form resultant url

```
Constants.Swift
import Foundation

private struct Domains {

    static let Local = "localhost IP"
   static let QA = "QA.Environment"
    static let UAT = "http://test-UAT.com"

}

// HardCoded URLRoutes

    private struct URLRoutes{

        static let query = "query=bitcoin&"
        static let date = "date=2019-04-04&"
        static let sortBy = "sortBy=Date&"

    }

        private static let constructionURL = Domain.local+URLRoutes.query + URLRoutes.date + URLRoutes.sortBy  + API.Key

        static var ResultantURL: String {
            return constructionURL
        }
```

I am trying to make this dynamic to pass value from other class to form the dynamic url.

```
    private struct URLRoutes{

        var query : String
        var date : String?
        var sortBy : String?         
    }
```

From another Class trying to access the resultant URL
      url = URL(string: URLRoutes.ResultantURL)!

but how can I construct the formate of url from the another class?

```
    static let query = "query=bitcoin&"
    static let date = "date=2019-04-04&"
    static let sortBy = "sortBy=Date&"
```

Your inputs will guide me.

Comment: Not related, but why not use `URLQueryItems` instead of hardcode the string values?

Comment: What does "construct the formate of url from the another class" mean? Unclear what the problem is here.

Comment: How to pass values to struct which is created in constants.swift.  from another view controller.  The resultant for this is url formation.

Comment: You're just pushing the nonsense back another level: what does "pass values to struct" mean? _Show_ what you're trying to do and why you can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's playground code that does what you want:

```
struct API {
    static let Key = "ABC123"
}

struct URLRoutes{

    var query : String
    var date : String?
    var sortBy : String?

    var constructionURL: String {
        return  query + (date ?? "") + (sortBy  ?? "") + API.Key
    }
}

let query = "query=bitcoin&"
let date = "date=2019-04-04&"
let sortBy = "sortBy=Date&"

let myRoute = URLRoutes(query: query, date: date, sortBy: sortBy)

print(myRoute.constructionURL)
```

However, this isn't really ideal and doesn't use the constructs that Apple provides.  Here's another approach:

```
struct URLRoute {
    var queryItems:[URLQueryItem]

    init(query: String, date:String?, sortBy:String?) {
        queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "query", value: query),
            URLQueryItem(name: "date", value: date),
            URLQueryItem(name: "sortBy", value: sortBy),
            URLQueryItem(name: "api_key", value: API.Key)
        ]
    }

    var constructionURL:String {
        get {
            var component = URLComponents(string: "")
            component?.queryItems = queryItems
            return component?.string ?? ""
        }
    }
}

let betterRoute = URLRoute(query: "bitcoin", date: "2019-04-04", sortBy: "Date")
print(betterRoute.constructionURL)
```

You can use `URLComponents` to do lots of heavy lifting for you in creating valid URLs.

Comment: Thanks David its helps me.

Comment: @kiran please accept the answer if it solves your issue.